Separate a GIF file into 2 files
I am working with a Delphi program that communicate with an ATMEL 2560 (ATM2560). This ATM2560 receives commands from the Delphi program and moves a Servo according to the commands. The ATM2560 then gives feed back to the Delphi program which updates a EDITbox (showing the position).  That part is working satisfactory.
Now I want to make the program to use a graphical approach.  I have on the WWW found a GIF-file showing practical all positions ( -90 degrees to +90 degrees) . But unfortunately this GIF-file contains 2 columns (is the the right word ?) of a servo-animation.  LEFT column is a positon servo and the RIGHT column servo is a rotation servo. Left servo goes from -90 degrees to + 90 degrees and back to -90 degrees in 42 frames. The right servo does a full rotation in 42 frames thereby synchronizing the 2 colums.
I an a newbie in Delphi animation knowing nothing to absolutely nothing about animation, so I need some help.
I downloaded the GIFIMAGE unit and installed it in my Delphi D7 Enterprize on an XP (sp4).
After a lot of "try and error's" and a lot of download (mostly StackExchange pages) I have managed now to open the file, extract each frame, and save it a a BMP.bitmap.  But What i want is to separate the frame into 2 halves (one half is the position servo frame and the other half is the rotational servo frame).  I have absolutely no ideas how to do that. Please help.
Here is my code:
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, GifImage, XPman, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
     Gif : TGifImage;

    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1 : TForm1;
  BMP   : TBitmap;
  Curdir : String;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   I : Integer;

begin
   Curdir := 'g:\servo\';
   GIF := TGifImage.Create();
   Gif.LoadFromFile(Curdir + 'servos-1.gif');
   Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
   Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   BMP.Free;
   GIF.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
   i  : Integer;
begin
//   Bmp.Width := Gif.Width div 2;
   Bmp.Height := Gif.Height;
   For i := 0 to Gif.Images.Count-1 do
     begin
        Bmp.Width := Gif.Width div 2;
        Bmp.Assign(Gif.Images.SubImages[i].Bitmap);
        Bmp.SaveToFile(Curdir + 'Serv' + IntToStr(i) + '.bmp');
     END;
end;

END.


It is not clear what you are actually asking for, and there seems to be a lot of details provided that are not relevant to the actual problem. Can you please simplify the question and clarify the actual problem?

I want to divide the GIF file into 2 halves. One half has the SERVO POSITION part of the GIF file and the other half has the SERVO ROTATIONAL part of the GIF-file.  Same number of frames, but obly one "column" and 2 GIF files.

Since you have aleady split the image into multiple BMPs, place these as bitmap resources into your project and display them as/when wanted.

You already know how to extract each GIF frame into a TBitmap.  Now you just need to create smaller TBitmaps for each frame, eg:
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
  bmpFrame, bmpHalf: TBitmap;
  rDest, rFrame1stHalf, rFrame2ndHalf: TRect;
begin
  bmpFrame := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    bmpFrame.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

    bmpHalf := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmpHalf.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
      bmpHalf.Width := Gif.Width div 2;
      bmpHalf.Height := Gif.Height;

      rDest := Rect(0, 0, bmpHalf.Width, bmpHalf.Height);
      rFrame1stHalf := Rect(0, 0, bmpHalf.Width, bmpHalf.Height);
      rFrame2ndHalf := Rect(bmpHalf.Width, 0, Gif.Width, Gif.Height);

      for i := 0 to Gif.Images.Count-1 do
      begin
        bmpFrame.Assign(Gif.Images.SubImages[i].Bitmap);

        bmpHalf.Canvas.CopyRect(rDest, bmpFrame.Canvas, rFrame1stHalf);
        // do something with bmpHalf (1st half) ...

        bmpHalf.Canvas.CopyRect(rDest, bmpFrame.Canvas, rFrame2ndHalf);
        // do something with bmpHalf (2nd half) ...

      end;
    finally
      bmpHalf.Free;
    end;
  finally
   bmpFrame.Free;
  end
end;

